# administrator permissions on a SSAS database

Tags: sql-server, permissions, ssas, ssas-2016

I had a third party company coming over and building ssas databases to produce reports.

They did, but now the DBA wants to have a look but I haven't got permissions, to even see those databases, as you can see on the picture below.

Can I grant myself administrator permissions?

I am system administrator. there is a AD group called `SQLDBA` and

[image]

When right-cliking on the server-properties-security-Add-
then adding my AD group `SQLDBA` it says I don't have the permissions to `alter` the server object as you can see on the picture below.

I had previously added that `sqldba` AD group as an administrator to that box.

[image]

### TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Either the 'mycompany\MMiorelli' user does not have permission to alter the 'myserver\instance' object, or the object does not exist.
 (Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AppLocal.Core)

---

BUTTONS:

OK

Comment: right click on the SSAS server node and go to Properties; Security. Are there any names in there? Can you add your name to the list?

Comment: Try to use "Run as administrator" when running SSMS, it solved the same problem for me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

from the comments by  [Denis Rubashkin](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/145949/denis-rubashkin)

> Try to use "Run as administrator" when running SSMS, it solved the
>   same problem for me

and that worked for me too.

to run ssms `as and administrator` press the `shift` and `right click` on the ssms icon and that will give the options below:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The SSAS permissions are completely independent from SQL Server permissions.

If you don't have permissions, there is one hope:

> By default, members of the local Administrators group are also granted
>   administrative rights in Analysis Server. Although the local group is
>   not explicitly granted membership in the Analysis Services server
>   administrator role, local administrators can create databases, add
>   users and permissions, and perform any other task allowed to system
>   administrators. The implicit granting of administrator permissions is
>   configurable. It is determined by the BuiltinAdminsAreServerAdmins
>   server property, which is set to true by default.

**Source**: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/instances/grant-server-admin-rights-to-an-analysis-services-instance?view=sql-analysis-services-2017

I suggest you to read the link above and try to run your Management Studio using an account that is member of `Local Administrators` group of your SSAS Server